# How to bind window resize event to plugin instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a jQuery plugin and I need to make it respond to the window resize event.  The problem I'm having is that it works fine if you only have one instance of the plugin but if you only more that one instance only the later works.  My plugin code looks something like

```
(function ($) {

    //Define it
    var MyPlugin = function (element, options) {
       //...
    };

    MyPlugin.prototype.init = function() {
        $that = this;
        $(window).bind('resize',function(e) {
            //This only seems to get called for the last instance of the plugin
            $that.recalculate();
        });
    }

    MyPlugin.prototype.recalculate = function() {
    }

    $.fn.myPlugin = function (option) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this   = $(this);
            var options = typeof(option) === 'object' ? option : {};
            new MyPlugin(this, options));
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

The problem is that the window resize event isn't called for every instance of the plugin so if I have two instance like so, only `div2` will work.

```
$('.div1').myPlugin();
$('.div2').myPlugin();
```

Comment: where is `$that` defined, and what does the resize handler do? (you're assumption that only the last handler is called is almost certainly wrong)

Comment: @Amit I've updated the code to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

I think no way to execute window resize multiple times for each instance.
trying to create a global array to store the instances, and recover it when resizing.

```
var instances = [] ;

(function ($) {

    //Define it
    var MyPlugin = function (element, options) {
        instances.push(this);
        this.element = element;
        this.init();
    };

    MyPlugin.prototype.init = function() {
        $that = this;
        $(window).bind('resize',function(e) {
            $that.recalculate();
        });
    }

    MyPlugin.prototype.recalculate = function() {
        for(i in instances)
            console.log('recalculate', instances[i].element.html());
    }

    $.fn.myPlugin = function (option) {
        var options = typeof(option) === 'object' ? option : {};
        return new MyPlugin(this, options);
    };
}(jQuery));

$('.div1').myPlugin();
$('.div2').myPlugin();
```

see an example https://jsfiddle.net/kbggthb0/5/

Answer (score -1):

try to change your code using the code below

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function (option) {
    var options = typeof(option) === 'object' ? option : {};
    return new MyPlugin(this, options);
};
```